# Is it possible to parse tags in an entry?

Tags: channel-entries, tags

Is there any way to put EE tags in entries, by entering the tag in a textarea of a channel entry for example?

I know there was an old plugin that enabled this, but is there anything for EE5?

Thanks.

Comment: By tags you mean {exp:channel:entries....   Or simply snippet|partials or variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can install the '[Allow-EEcode](https://github.com/EllisLab/Allow-Eecode)' add-on.  But you should think carefully before doing so - there are all sorts of sensible warnings on the github page.  **Almost** always you can find a way to refactor what you are doing to not require use of this add-on.

HTH

Comment: Yes, absolutely don't use this add-on (no offense to the quality of the add-on, I'm sure it works fine). You should never need that functionality to accomplish anything in EE, and you open a can of worms that will be a huge paint o re-lid down the line.